# SQL Server : display Top 10 Companies, %, and number of times worked with each company using specific from/to dates

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to get the top 10 companies we work with (within a specific from/to dates) and display their company name and the % of how much we work with this company, and the number of times we worked with them.

Example:

```
TOP 10 COMPANIES WE WORK WITH (from 1/1/2015 until 7/15/2015) ARE:
------------------------------------------------------------------
IBM   -  50 %    (500 times this year)
APPLE -  10 %    (100 times this year)
INTEL -   4.5 %  ( 45 times this year)
....and so on...
```

TABLE/RECORD EXAMPLE.

```
    Table Name: Table1
    WRK_ID | COMPANY_NAME | COMPANY_ID | WRK_DATE   | INV_AMOUNT | and so on...
    123    | IBM          | 22         | 01/28/2015 | 1,500.00   |
    128    | INTEL        | 30         | 01/15/2015 |   750.75   |
    129    | APPLE        | 19         | 04/25/2015 |   241.10   |
    123    | IBM          | 22         | 07/08/2015 |   150.00   |
    .........    and so on ..........
```

This is what I have tried so far:

```
SET ROWCOUNT 10

SELECT 
    COMPANY_ID, COUNT(WRK_ID) AS COUNT
FROM TABLE1
GROUP BY COMPANY_ID
ORDER BY COUNT(WRK_ID) DESC
```

Comment: I would give it to you for free :)

Comment: Sooner or later I will find the answer or learn how to do it myself and I will post the answer here, just trying to see if I can save myself some time.

Comment: I did try alot of things, give me a sec to find it and paste it but its probably funny to ppl that really know and understand MS SQL.

Comment: @believeme that's why I'm here, I need help.

Comment: I edited my question and added what I did so far, Thanks for the help ?

Comment: What is your definition of top 10? Most interactions or 10 largest %? Some other criteria?

Comment: @StarPilot sorry, most interactions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Need cte or variable to store the total count to get percent

```
WITH cte AS
(
    SELECT  
        COMPANY_NAME,
        COUNT(*) OVER() AS TotalCount
    FROM
        Company
    WHERE 
        WRK_DATE >= '20150101' AND WRK_DATE < '20150715'
)
SELECT TOP 10 WITH TIES
    COMPANY_NAME,
    CONCAT(CONVERT(VARCHAR,(COUNT(*) * 100) / TotalCount), ' %') AS Perc,
    CONCAT('(', CONVERT(VARCHAR, COUNT(*)), ' times this year)') AS Cnt
FROM cte 
GROUP BY COMPANY_NAME, TotalCount
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a CTE to get the total number of jobs between the start date and end date then use that in a straight forward `GROUP BY` query

```
DECLARE @StartDate DATETIME
DECLARE @EndDate DATETIME

SET @StartDate = '20140101'
SET @EndDate = '20141231';

WITH  TotalCTE
AS (
     SELECT
      COUNT(*) AS TotalCount
     FROM
      ATable
     WHERE
      WRK_DATE BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate
   )
SELECT
  COMPANY_NAME,
  ( COUNT(*) / TotalCount ) * 100.0 AS Percentage,
  COUNT(*) AS CountOfJobs
FROM
  ATable
  CROSS JOIN TotalCTE
WHERE
  WRK_DATE BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate
GROUP BY
  COMPANY_NAME
```

Comment: this won't compile.. you have to use TotalCount in your group by.. plus you're dividing before you multiply by 100 which will give you zeros for percents